# sporadic network connection with windows 8

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, internet-connection

Got the Samsung Series 5 ultrabook with Intel Centrino 6235 adapter in February 2013 and found that the network connection sporadically times out, but it goes back to normal on Restart. It is not the router because I have other working devices running off it too and they don't have this problem. I have the latest Intel driver, turned off Bluetooth, etc, Other than replacing the wireless/bluetooth card, any suggestions?

Comment: Might be your power settings - wireless card might be going into a standby mode and not waking properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your anti-virus program and your power options ? Does the machine run all the time or does it hibernate ? Also check your network services, mainly the Network Connection service, the Workstation and Server service and any other vital network services. Also check your device driver or settings itself ; maybe it has a suspend function or bugs our when the laptop goes into sleep mode / hibernation.

What you can do so that you don't need to restart: Maybe it works. I have a similar problem with my Acer One Netbook wireless connection and also on my work PC and it's wired LAN connection. I run a batch file with the following content :

> ipconfig /release&ipconfig /renew&ipconfig /flushdns&ipconfig /registerdns

To do this, create simple text file, then rename it so that it has a "bat" extension. Then, edit the file and copy and paste the above text into it. Save and exit text application, then run the batch file.

You can also try :

**1.)** to disable and re-enable the network connection.

**2.)** use the windows network troubleshooter or "troubleshoot problems" wizard.

**3.)** update BIOS (*advanced tech, use caution!*).